# How to create Radio buttons with 2-Way Exclusivity in JavaFx

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I want to build something like [this](https://css-tricks.com/radio-buttons-with-2-way-exclusivity/). From a ***k*** value and *Map<String,List>* I want to build a scoring system, the ***k*** value is the number of the maximum vote, the map has as keys the names of
some groups of people and as values the list of people's names.

Here we have a ugly and not working preview with ***k***=3

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
</tr>
Group1
<tr>
    <td>Name11</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name12</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name13</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
</tr>
<br>
Group2
<tr>
    <td>Name21</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name22</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-5" name="col-1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-5"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-5"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: The supplied example code is html, not JavaFX. If you want help with a JavaFX solution, provide a [mcve], written in JavaFX.

Comment: Even that aside, it is not clear what you are asking and how the groups have a bearing on the solution. Are radio buttons an appropriate control to be a part of the solution? E.g., you could use a multiple-selection listview, or multiple single selection listviews instead. What happens when somebody selects K+1 items (is a LRU algorithm invoked or something else)?  Allow only a single selection in each of the groups or multiple selections in a list?  Is selecting a name in each group mandatory optional? What is "2-Way Exclusivity"? etc.

Comment: @jewelsea the supplied example is to help to understand how to fit the groups, the names and the buttons. Sorry I am completely in the dark and I cannot provide a minimal reproducible example written in JavaFX. I don't know why you're complicating your life by adding more assumptions. The "2-Way Exclusivity" is the mutual exclusivity by two way (eg. row and column) see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity

Comment: @smallcode, please note that when you need help from someone, you need to provide as much clear information as possible. So that others can directly focus on the issue. Remember that they have to spend their valueble time to answer your issues. It is your duty to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: @saidandem I know dude, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with what @jewelsea mentioned in the comments. Having said that, after going through the demo in the link, I thought to give a try and see how this can be achieved.

So far the trick I am using is:

- Set toggle groups on either by rows or columns.
- Create a two
  dimensional array by the opposite of what you choosed for toogle
  groups. I mean,

  - if you choose toggle groups by rows, then create a
    2D array by columns as first dimension.
  - if you choose toggle groups by columns, then create a
    2D array by rows first dimension.

Now when a radio button is selected, the toggle group will take care of one dimension toggling..and all you need is to check the other dimension radioButtons and select the correct one.

Below is the code of the logic:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TwoWayRadioButtonDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        int k = 4;
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(50));
        root.setHgap(60);
        root.setVgap(60);

        RadioButton[][] buttons = new RadioButton[k][k];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
            double r = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                RadioButton radio = new RadioButton();
                radio.setToggleGroup(tg);
                buttons[j][i] = radio;
                int c = j;
                radio.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
                    if (val) {
                        for (int t = 0; t < buttons[c].length; t++) {
                            buttons[c][t].setSelected(t == r);
                        }
                    }
                });
                root.add(radio, j, i);
            }
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("2 Way Radio Button");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this, thanks!

Comment: I see you are a new contributor, and it looks like this answered your question. The usual thing is to click the up arrow ("This answer is useful") and mark this as the solution.